# How do you ascertain that the battery drain in an iPhone is software related

Tags: battery, charging, iphone

So, my iPhone 6 Plus battery has been draining very badly.

Whereas I used to get over a day on a single 100% charge, I barely make it half a day now. Even the charging in takes whole night even on a 10W iPad charger.

Everything I have observed lends me to believe that it is a battery issue. However the Apple Diagnosis concludes that the battery is alright and the problem probably is software related.

From the battery usage of the last day or of the last week, I don't see any app consuming too much battery - Gmail background activity even when it's background activity has been disabled is the only suspicion.

In the diagnostics and logs, obviously there's a ton of diagnostic information.

Reinstalling all of these and restoring the 64G of data is a painful process, I'd avoid unless I'm sure it would fix the issue that currently exists.

Anyway I can ascertain that the battery drain right now is absolutely software related?

Comment: Taking all night to charge? Sure sounds like a hardware issue to me.

Comment: Could your edit your post to include a screenshot of your Battery Log? `Settings > General > Usage > Battery Usage > Battery Usage > Last 7 Days`